# Duplicates in a View with Taxonomy

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view that has a global combined fields filter setup to search through node's title and a set of taxonomy terms. It works fine but only if I include a "Taxonomy term: Name" field.

This field currently causes each node to appear in the results for each term that is assigned to it. I checked Aggregation Settings for that field but only have these options:[[image: options]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSAGP.png)

I also tried the Views Distinct module which worked but at a great performance cost. Is there either:

1. a way I can include terms in the global combine fields filter that I haven't thought of or
2. a way to prevent the duplicate results?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **GROUP BY** or **DISTINCT** by enabling views aggregation settings to remove duplicate records.

1. Go and edit your view
2. In Advanced » OTHER section by enabling Use aggregation: Yes
3. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation
   settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code in your themes template.php file:**

```
function your-theme_views_pre_render(&$view) {
 $used_nids = array();
$new_view_result = array();

 if ($view->name == 'Name_of_your_view') {
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
    if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
      $new_view_result[] = $row;
      $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
    }
  }

$view->result = $new_view_result;
 }
}
```